# RelativeLayout TextView overlay

Tags: android, layout, textview, overlay, android-relativelayout

This is my current ListView item layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingTop="6dp"
android:paddingRight="6dp"
android:paddingBottom="6dp">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="6dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/departure_line"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:shadowColor="#000000"
        android:shadowDx="1"
        android:shadowDy="1"
        android:shadowRadius="1"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:paddingRight="3dp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/departure_destination"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="52dp"
    android:background="#777777"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/departure_time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

My problem is that the destination TextView overlays the time TextView as you can see on the screen. How to prevent that?

http://www.abload.de/image.php?img=screensk6y.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use     android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/departure_time" in your destination or you could set them both up in a TableLayout>

Comment: The only way to do that is to use a TableLayout, because a RelativeLayout always overlay TextViews in layout arrangements.

Comment: Actually that is not true as long as you define the textView's edges with layout it will go nearly wherever you want and height/width will stop where you tell it to

Comment: Thank you for the answer! And well done to the question asker for including the work "overlay" in the question. This made finding the solution just so much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Use the attribute:
android:layout_below="@id/label"

You can do this in one Relativelayout. And remove the orientation attribute from your RelativeLayout, it is useless.

You can do following:

- Use LinearLayout, there you have the attribute orientation.
- Use RelativeLayout and look into the layout_below attribute

Comment: Please correct me if I do something wrong. A added "android:layout_below="@+id/departure_destination"" to my time View, but now the time content is wrapped to a new line. Thats not what I want. The destination should not overlay the time view, they should be end before, and their text the should be truncated and filled with dots.

Comment: I understood you wrong. So the layout_below attribute does not solve your problem. Try the ALIGN_RIGHT attribute = "departure_time".

Answer (score 1):

```
android:ellipsize="end"
```

this will cut the text off if it is too long. or you can do

```
android:ellipsize="marquee"
```

and it will scroll like app names in android market. sometimes you have to throw

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

in there for it to work, also i would reccomend

```
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
```

so that it continues moving in case the user missed it the first time.

as seen in [Layout Tricks](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-efficiency.html),[TextView ellipsize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aellipsize)